# Is this a bad question? How can I improve it?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask the following question.  Is it a good question?  If not, how can it be improved?

> Smallers files its works but not for larger.
>
> $stri = "$namee -i \"$Vidpath\" -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -frames 1 -y
>   \"$pout\"";

Comment: It could be helpful for you to mention what you are actually trying to accomplish so people dont have to guess by looking at your code.

Comment: Major lack of detail in evidence here. When asking this on SO, add detail such as what you are trying to achieve, what programming language you are using, what errors you are getting and include any error logs.

Comment: Say what you mean by "doesn't work" (eg error, slow, incorrect, etc)

Comment: Some ways to improve it would be to answer:

 - what does it do? In proper detail.
 - what do you want it to do?
 - what else did you try?

Comment: See here for a good tutorial on asking questions - http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: @JoshMein yeah, oops. Comment duly pruned

Comment: This seems like an FFmpeg problem? Please always include the full uncut output with all debug messages etc

Comment: +1 for asking, but yes it's a bad question in its current form. If possible, the first step is to run the command from the command line

Comment: It succesfully converts the video to flv then gets videosnap in jpeg form and sets the path. It works properly for both for videos under 10min after that the video will still be converted to flv and play properly but the jpeg image wont be made for videos under 10min

Comment: I don't think this meta question justifies downvotes. Yes, the question is bad, but at least he's trying to figure out *why* and bring it into acceptable territory. A lot of this information is covered in the [FAQ]. Read it well, for it is your friend.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: Although I agree with you people are well within their rights to downvote this. The downvote reason is *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"* and this post quite clearly does not show any research effort. As you point out, a lot of this information is covered in the FAQ. If OP read the FAQ it is unlikely s/he would need to post this question here at all.

Comment: @JonW you're right, that was badly phrased. People can downvote whatever they want for whatever reason. I'm just trying to point out the bright side here. Every user properly educated about Stack Exchange is a bonus IMO.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, this is a bad question.

> Smallers files its works but not for larger.

Works how?  What are you trying to do?  How small are the files that it works on?  How large are the files that it doesn't work on? What output are you getting when it doesn't work?  No output, or an error message?  Post that if you get anything.

Give people all of the information that they need to answer the question.  Pretend that you know nothing about this problem except what you posted.  Is that enough information for someone to answer you?  Is there more code around that line that you could post that might be important to the question?  Post it.  *Explain what that code is doing!*  Don't make me work to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your help I understand the errors of my way.

Comment: @alex And now that you have some suggestions, you can go back to your question and edit it before it's actually closed, improving it as much as you can. =)

Answer (score 3):

One simple way to improve this question (but by no means the only way) would be to wrap your code in a code block - makes it much easier to read...

Indent your code with four spaces :

```
$stri = "$namee -i \"$Vidpath\" -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -frames 1 -y \"$pout\"";
```

Or surround it with back ticks :

`$stri = "$namee -i \"$Vidpath\" -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -frames 1 -y \"$pout\"";`

**This is most definitely not the only thing that can be done**, but the other answer[s] pretty much cover everything else I could think of.

Comment: Simple, necessary, but not sufficient. The question would be better, but still pretty bad.

Comment: @joa - not at all sufficient by itself... However there wasn't much I could add to Bill's answer and no one else mentioned formatting. Just adding my 2 cents...

Comment: Well, can you change the "One simple way to improve this question" to something that sounds less...uuuhhh...wrong? Like "One thing you should always to and lookout for..." or something? Because I got the urge to downvote you into the ground for implying that that would be enough.

Answer (score -2):

My thread recently got closed Evan though I did my best to give a good outline of the question. In a comment I edited it to give more information. I don't want to waste anyone's time but is this still not up to standard [FFMPEG unable to take frame and save as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003561/ffmpeg-to-take-videosnap)

Comment: If you'd add the actual error message, the question might get reopened. Especially since you've got some people looking at it now. It's a simple rule, really: if you get *any* warning or error message, include it *fully* in your post.

Comment: Yeah I was going to do it in the morning . Evan then I don't think that's where the bug is it might be to do with apache configuration and file size

Comment: @alex yeah, but we can't just magically know that without any information from you. The usual thing to do is to debug - ie. looking at the error messages and deducting what's wrong. That's what all programmers do, even the best ones

Comment: Yeah obviously but would all that information eft fit into the question