# How long does it take to get banned from posting questions, and should there be a rule change to this?

Tags: discussion

I've tried editing [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003561/ffmpeg-to-take-frame-and-save-as-image) and fixing it up. What else could I do, and when do you draw the line to say when someone should be banned from asking questions? Maybe I should just give up and try elsewhere. Should there be a change to this rule?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Are you saying you are currently banned?

Comment: Yes im banned for asking questions . Im just abit upset becasue I now cant get help for solving the problem i have

Comment: why would you downgrade this its legitiment

Comment: [Votes on Meta are different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @alex: you asked [a Meta question about improving your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168452/is-this-a-bad-question-how-can-i-improve-it), for which you received primarily upvotes and many excellent suggestions. You even commented that you "understood the error of [your] ways" and would improve the question. However, it wasn't until [11 hours later](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15003561/revisions) that you took anyone's advice and added the error message to the question, and you disregarded other great advice for improving it.

Comment: yeah it was 3 in the morning when i gave it . so the next morning i posted it whats the problem with that im not going to spend all night on here

Comment: Furthermore, rather than listen to people on the Meta question, you [first posted a duplicate on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016151/ffmpeg-to-get-video-snap), then [posted a duplicate on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168546/what-else-do-i-have-to-add-to-make-this-question-open). That just wastes everyone's time. Beyond that, your spelling and sentence construction show that you don't put a lot of effort into your questions.

Comment: well nobody was giving me any any anwsers and i wanted to fix it quickly.

Comment: Look at ffmpeg questions and compare them to mine not much diffrence at all.

Comment: Nobody was giving you answers because you weren't asking a question anybody could *possibly* answer.

Comment: so nobody uses ffmpeg or has saved an image from a video frame?

Answer (score 2):

If you read [the link you were given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) when you were question-banned, you will see the following reasons listed as users who typically get banned:

> users who can't be bothered to form sentences
>
> users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do

Both of these describe the question you were banned for. Your original version of the question simply stated:

```
Smallers files its works but not for largers.

$stri = "$namee -i \"$Vidpath\" -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -frames 1 -y \"$pout\"";
```

I don't know whether English is your first language, but it's understandable if it's not, and that's not a reason in itself for being banned. However, even if it's not you don't show effort in communicating what you are trying to do, and you don't bother to use complete sentences or proper spelling and syntax.

Comment: I was half asleep and then i edited it . Is this an english test or something?

Comment: The question was unreadable and unanswerable. If you can't be bothered to post a readable question, why should this site bother to answer you?

Comment: @alex Asking a question is a *communication* skill. You need to be able to communicate effectively.

Comment: I thought it was a programming site not a blog review

Comment: @alex: In saying that you don't think you should have to write complete sentences or explain your own problem in a way that can be understood, you are demonstrating *exactly* why you were banned.

Comment: What cant you understand about this

Comment: Im trying to save an image from a video frame and save it as a jpeg.
This function works for smaller video files, but if the video is over 10 minutes it won't save the jpeg image. An error comes up as before trans.

    public function VideoToJpeg($localVideoPath, $localOutImgPath)
    {
  $Name = dirname(__FILE__) . "/ffmpeg";
  $Str = "$Name -i \"$localVideoPath\" -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y \"$localOutImgPath\"";
  
  exec($Str);
    }

here is the error I got from ffmpeg 

    [NULL @ 0370e760] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'path'
    : Invalid argument

Comment: Posting the text of your question in every textarea you see on the site will probably not result in an answer.

Comment: well i think my questions is good .If you guys dont have the knowledge to anwser it dont bother mariking it down or jsut say where to edit it.

Comment: @alex It is difficult to understand your question. Note that this is different from saying "it is difficult to find a solution to your problem", which may or may not be true. The former has to do with your communicative abilities. The latter has to do with the knowledge and capacity of SO users.

Comment: @alex: Nice try (a lot of users banned for low quality questions say "don't downvote it just because you don't know the answer.") Anyway, multiple users [did tell you how to edit your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168452/is-this-a-bad-question-how-can-i-improve-it). For the most part, you ignored them.

Comment: My question was relevant. Alright have you used ffmpeg before?

Comment: I didnt ignore them I edited my question numerous times to make the moderaters happy

Comment: Let us say I have. This does not make your question more or less relevant. Additionally, the main issue here is that the problem you are facing cannot be understood from your question (whether or not it is relevant can only be decided once we can understand it)

Comment: Alright how would you word the problem then or how would you ask a question? if your the expert I need to learn give me an example please this is getting really frustrating.The question is on ffmpeg by the way

Comment: @alex With your recent edit (including the additional information requested) your post has been reopened.

Comment: That makes me happy well I Knew it was a good question.

Comment: No. It was an atrociously bad question. It **has become** a better question.